# Integral $\int_{b}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - b^2}}{e^{c x} - 1} \; dx$

Tags: integration, calculus

> Calculate $$\int_{b}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - b^2}}{e^{cx} - 1} \; dx$$

Where $b,c >0$ are some real constants.

Comment: This belongs on [math.se]

Comment: Have you tried to substitute $x^2-b^2 =t^2$? // nevermind OP doesn't have a MSE account since the question is migrated.

Comment: I tried, but I fall into an integral that seems to be even worse and that I do not know how to solve either.

Comment: Since the question has been migrated from the physics site I am guessing the integral has some particular physical significance. Is this the case, and if so, perhaps you could let us know as it may (?) be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I have something which may or may not be useful. You can first write
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sqrt{x^2 - b^2}}{\mathrm{e}^{cx}-1} \, = \, \sqrt{x^2 - b^2} \, \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-cx}}{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-cx}} \, = \,\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \, \sqrt{x^2 - b^2} \, \mathrm{e}^{-kcx} \, .
\end{equation}
Integrating each of those terms over $x$ from $b$ to $\infty$ gives, up to a factor, modified Bessel functions of the second kind $K_{n=1}$(see equation 7 in [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html)) and are all convergent given your assumptions $b > 0$ and $c>0$. This then produces
\begin{equation}
\int^{\infty}_{b} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - b^2}}{\mathrm{e}^{cx}-1} \,\mathrm{d}x \, = \, \frac{b}{c} \, \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{1}{k} \, K_{n=1}\left(k b c\right) \, .
\end{equation}

Comment: It is very useful, for sure. I do not see any way to compute the given integral even using special functions.

Answer (score 1):

*This is too long for a comment.*

In my humble opinion, I think that the solution given by @secavara is the most practical and I dont see any way to compute the integral even using special functions.

Let $a=bc$ to make
$$I(b,c)= \, \frac{b}{c} \, \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{K_1(a k)}{k}$$ Numerically, for a given $a$, the summation converges quite fast. For example, considering, for a few values of $a$,
$$S_n(a)=\sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac{K_1(a k)}{k}$$
we have for six significant figures (which I suppose would be sufficient for a problem from physics)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & n & S_n(a) \\
 0.5& 1 & 1.65644 \\
 0.5& 2 & 1.95739 \\
 0.5& 3 & 2.04986 \\
 0.5& 4 & 2.08482 \\
 0.5& 5 & 2.09960 \\
 0.5& 6 & 2.10629 \\
 0.5& 7 & 2.10947 \\
 0.5& 8 & 2.11103 \\
 0.5& 9 & 2.11182 \\
 0.5& 10 & 2.11222 \\
 0.5& 11 & 2.11243 \\
 0.5& 12 & 2.11255 \\
 0.5& 13 & 2.11261 \\
 0.5& 14 & 2.11264 \\
 0.5& 15 & 2.11266 \\
 0.5& 16 & 2.11267 \\
 0.5& 17 & 2.11267 \\
 0.5& 18 & 2.11267 \\
 0.5& 19 & 2.11268 \\
 & & \\
 1.0 & 1 & 0.601907 \\
 1.0 & 2 & 0.671840 \\
 1.0 & 3 & 0.685226 \\
 1.0 & 4 & 0.688347 \\
 1.0 & 5 & 0.689155 \\
 1.0 & 6 & 0.689379 \\
 1.0 & 7 & 0.689444 \\
 1.0 & 8 & 0.689464 \\
 1.0 & 9 & 0.689470 \\
 1.0 & 10 & 0.689472 \\
 & & \\
  1.5& 1 & 0.277388 \\
 1.5& 2 & 0.297466 \\
 1.5& 3 & 0.299825 \\
 1.5& 4 & 0.300161 \\
 1.5& 5 & 0.300214 \\
 1.5& 6 & 0.300223 \\
 1.5& 7 & 0.300225 \\
 & & \\
 2.0 & 1 & 0.139866 \\
 2.0 & 2 & 0.146108 \\
 2.0 & 3 & 0.146556 \\
 2.0 & 4 & 0.146594 \\
 2.0 & 5 & 0.146598 \\
 2.0 & 6 & 0.146599  
\end{array}
\right)$$ So, if $a=bc\geq 1$, we should not need to add many terms.

Being myself a physicist, what I should do is to generate a detailed table of $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{K_1(a k)}{k}$ and use interpolation for any $a$ absent in the table.

In any manner, you could find very simple subroutines in [*"Numerical Recipes"*](ftp://tech.obihiro.ac.jp/suzuki/Numerical_Recipes_in_Fortran.pdf) for the comutation of $K_1(x)$ (see subroutine *bessk1* in page $232$ of the linked page; it also requires subroutine *bessi1* in page $231$ of the same document).

We could know in advance the number of terms to be added for a given accuracy since, using a quick and dirty regression,
$$\log_{10} \left(\frac{K_1(x)}{x}\right)\approx A\,x^B+C$$ with
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 A & -0.60312 & 0.00728 & \{-0.61758,-0.58866\} \\
 B & +0.94056 & 0.00250 & \{+0.93561,+0.94552\} \\
 C & -0.32905 & 0.04909 & \{-0.42649,-0.23161\} \\
\end{array}$$ $(R^2=0.999984)$ making that, for a precision equal to $10^{-6}$, about $\frac {11} a$ terms should be required.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all of you for your attention. I understood perfectly what was done by @secavara and also by @Claude Leibovici. Now I have a curiosity: if one of these constants (b or c) are complex, would this solution still be valid? For example: if b is complex and c is real (or if $b^2$ is complex). If it is not valid, would there be any?